# Est JS - Multiple container rendering

Tags: extjs

My application has a single container which loads when the application is called.
Lets call it as main container, In that I have many links, on click of one the link,it should load me another container(having same details as main container, which I will modify later based on requirement) in a different page.

I am able to call both the containers in a single page when the application is loaded.

Can you please explain in detail for my query. Your help is much appreciated.
let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "different page"? Are you just asking how to add/remove containers dynamically?

Comment: I mean the second container needs to be opened in new tab by the click of some link displayed in first container.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? It might make your question more clear.